# Google Classic VPN stopped working after an outage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

Please help!

My google cloud classic VPN to on prem network stopped working yesterday after a network outage.

The VPN is established on site on cisco asa but the pkt dcaps are 0. The tunnel is active.

The google log has warnings like this:  "Warning: Local traffic selectors narrowed for Child SA: *vpn_x.x.x.x*. Configured TS: [0.0.0.0/0  ], negotiated TS:[10.210.3.8/32 10.210.0.0/16  ]. Please verify configuration on the remote side."

I have not changed any configuration on the asa or on gcp side. Can someone please help me on what might be going on here? I will really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very likely indicates that the Traffic Selectors are configured differently on two sides. Please unify the TS configuration for GCP VPN tunnel and on-prem and re-create the tunnel if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I reconfigured both side to route based. But it didnt work at 1st. 2 days later its back up and working. Thank you for your help!